# Service call to re-enable touchplugin results in timeout

Tags: gazebo

I'm new to gazebo and currently struggeling with the service request to re-enable an already activated contact sensor.

This is my service request call:

```
gz service -s /sensor_contact/enable --reqtype gz.msgs.Boolean --reptype gz.msgs.Boolean --timeout 3000 --req 'data: true'
```

This is my sdf file:

```
<model name='barrier' canonical_link='body'>
<pose relative_to='ground_plane'>3.5 0 1 0 0 0</pose>
<link name='body'>
    <collision name='collision1'>
        <geometry>
            <box>
                <size>0.1 2.0 2.0</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>
        ...
    </collision>
    <sensor name='sensor_contact' type='contact'>
        <contact>
            <collision>collision1</collision>
        </contact>
    </sensor>
</link>
<plugin filename="gz-sim-touchplugin-system" name="gz::sim::systems::TouchPlugin">
    <target>vehicle_blue</target>
    <namespace>sensor_contact</namespace>
    <time>0.001</time>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</plugin>
</model>
```

Requesting the topic works fine for the first collision.
Also requesting a service to reset the simulation is working:

```
gz service -s /world/car_world/control --reqtype gz.msgs.WorldControl --reptype gz.msgs.Boolean --timeout 3000 --req 'reset: {all: true}'
```

So it must be a specific problem to my service request itself.

Edit: See also following link for the [TouchPlugin documentation](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/classgz_1_1sim_1_1systems_1_1TouchPlugin.html).